# Does stringWithContentsOfURL use the system proxy settings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, proxy, system

I am using the following code to fetch the contents of a web page but it needs to follow all the network rules etc as defined in the user's system prefs

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thetalkingcloud.com/static/ping_desktop_app.php?v=1.0"];
    NSError *theNetworkError;
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&theNetworkError];
```

**Specifically, does `stringWithContentsOfURL` connect using the system wide proxy settings?** (if there are any defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some tcpdumps between Safari and an Obj-C program using `stringWithContentsOfURL`. Safari respected my proxy while `stringWithContentsOfURL` did not.

Comment: Hmmm, do you know of an alternative to stringWithContentsOfURL that doesn't use event functions?
Thanks :)

Comment: Look into the NSURLConnections sendSynchronousRequest method.